# java : spring rest WS - Unable to locate object to be marshalled in a model

Tags: spring, rest, jaxb

Getting the exception while trying to run rest ws in spring mvc 3.0 with jaxb

> javax.servlet.ServletException: Unable to locate object to be marshalled in model: 
>   {org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.employees=org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 0 errors, employees=spring3.rest.bean.EmployeeList@13d1402}

My rest-servlet.xml file has jaxb entry as follow

```
<bean id="employees" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">
 <constructor-arg ref="jaxbMarshaller" />
</bean>
```

and

```
 <bean id="employeeController" class="spring3.rest.controller.EmployeeController">
  <property name="employeeDS" ref="employeeDS" /> 
  <property name="jaxb2Mashaller" ref="jaxbMarshaller" />
 </bean>
```

EmployeeController is :

```
@Controller
public class EmployeeController {

private EmployeeDS employeeDS;

public void setEmployeeDS(EmployeeDS ds) {
    this.employeeDS = ds;
}

private Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Mashaller;

public void setJaxb2Mashaller(Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Mashaller) {
    this.jaxb2Mashaller = jaxb2Mashaller;
}

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/employee/{id}")
public ModelAndView getEmployee(@PathVariable String id) {
    Employee e = employeeDS.get(Long.parseLong(id));
    return new ModelAndView("employees", "object", e);
}
```

In rest-servlet.xml

spring3.rest.bean.EmployeeList
         spring3.rest.bean.Employee

and both these beans are annoted with @XmlRootElement

Comment: @Controller
public class EmployeeController {

Comment: And we'll need to see the bean definition for `jaxbMarshaller` also

Answer (score 3):

Encountered similar problem, turns out that in my case I was returning List(A) while type 'A' itself is declared as @XmlRootElement, I was overlooking the fact that I was returning List of type A, had a wrapper object defined to hold the list and it was declared as @XMLRoolElement, able to move forward.

thought the post is old, might be helpful to know.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your response object to Model

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myPath", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
MyObjct getMyObject(ModelMap model) {
    MyObjct t = new MyObjct();
    model.addAttribute(t); // put into model
    return t;
}
```